# How java app for new version of windows will work on old version?

Tags: java, windows

So if I wrote an application for windows 8-10 on java, would it work for old versions like windows 98. And will it work correctly?
Both of them got the newest versions of JRE for example.

Comment: it depends if the code is portable... what about trying this out ? maybe post your code

Comment: I believe the latest version of Java that was supported on Win98 was Java 5 and it was unsupported in November 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't install Java 8 on systems older than Vista, so some programs might not run (specifically ones that use Java 8 features and APIs). Otherwise, they would work the same way, unless you do some sort of hacks that may break things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

If you had done your project in oldest version of java supported in vista/xp/windows 7 systems your application works perfectly it only depends on java environment once if it is satisfied your application will run without any compactability issues.